# MSBUILDでプロジェクトファイルエラーが起こってしまう。

Tags: windows, visual-studio, .net, cmake

実行環境
visual studio2019
windows10

cmake --build . --config RELEASE
cmake --build . --config RELEASE --target INSTALL

このコマンドを実行するとこのようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
C:\pytools\dlib\examples\build>cmake --build . --config RELEASE --target INSTALL
.NET Framework 向け Microsoft (R) Build Engine バージョン 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: プロジェクト ファイルが存在しません。
スイッチ: INSTALL.vcxproj
```

http://replication.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/05/210434
なのでこのページを参考にして解決できないと思い進んでいったんですが
MSBuildでソリューションをビルドするの箇所を実行してみても治りませんでした。.vcxprojファイルを指定したらいいのかと思い、これも実行してみたのすが結果は変わりませんでした。なにか解決法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: もう少し情報が無いと解決は難しそうです。たとえば、どのような設定で作ったどんなプロジェクトなのでしょうか。質問者が問題を再現するのに必要そうな情報を質問文を [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

これは回答では無く状況整理・確認です。
ちなみにこちらへマルチポストされていますね。[MSBUILDエラーが起こってしまう。](https://teratail.com/questions/275628)

質問の状況は、このページ [Dlib 最新版（バージョン 19.20.99）のインストール（Windows 上）](https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/dlib.html) の手順で作業していて、最後の「4.ビルド操作，インストール操作」で上記エラーが出たということと思われます。

指定された手順を追ってみると、「4.ビルド操作，インストール操作」の直前、サンプルプログラムのビルドの「2.cmake の操作」で行われた以下の操作の結果に`INSTALL.vcxproj`と`INSTALL.vcxproj.filters`というファイルは存在していません。

> ```
> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T host=x64 ^
>     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\pytools\dlib" ..
> ```

その前の手順である以下のものにはそれらが存在していました。

- Dlib のインストールの「6.cmake の操作」と「8.ビルド操作，インストール操作」
- Dlib 付属のツール類のインストールの「2.htmlify のビルドとインストール」
- Dlib 付属のツール類のインストールの「3.imglab のビルドとインストール」

ちなみにこのページ [VisualStudio2017でdlib C++を使う(ビルド編)](https://qiita.com/strv13570/items/a0542600532deee61391) だと画面上は`INSTALL.vcxproj`と`INSTALL.vcxproj.filters`ファイルが見えているけれどもそれに対する作業は行っていないようです。

そして「記述に従う」と書かれていた http://dlib.net/compile.html にも`C:/pytools/dlib/examples`フォルダの`CMakeLists.txt`にも`cmake --build . --config RELEASE --target INSTALL`の記述は出てこないので、**何か手順が変わって不要になったのかもしれません。あるいは何かの修正・更新時にバグが入り込んだのかもしれません。**

GPUを持っておらずCUDAが無いのでその影響かもしれませんが。

サンプルプログラムのビルドそのものは、`INSTALL`の付かないその前の行の`cmake --build . --config RELEASE`で済んでいて、`C:/pytools/dlib/examples/build/dlib_build/Release`と`C:/pytools/dlib/examples/build/Release`フォルダにライブラリと実行ファイルが出来ているので、残る作業は`INSTALL`と言ってもそれらのファイルをどこのフォルダにコピーするかだけだと思われます。

貴方が大学/研究室に関係ない第三者であれば推奨しませんが、一応問い合わせ先が明記されているし、記述内容の作業結果/整合性にかかわることなので、関係者ならばどうなっているのか問い合わせてみる手も考えられます。

---

なお関係は無いかもしれませんが、上記cmake結果のbuildフォルダの中に`examples.sln`というVisualStudio用ソリューションファイルが出来ていました。
試しにVisualStudioCommunity2019でそのソリューションをオープンして`ALL_BUILD`プロジェクトをビルドしてみたら途中までは実行できていました。
途中からヒープ容量が不足してビルドが進まなくなりましたが、それまでは出来ていました。